# (HTML) Browser Rendering GIFs slowly

Tags: javascript, html, image, photoshop

I've created a motion GIF, and implemented it into a web page button using some rollover javascript (button is static until rolled over, then switches to a preloaded animated once image). It's working perfectly, but the only catch is that the framerate is a bit lower than I expected. In Photoshop, I set the time to 'No Delay' so I figure this might be a limitation of GIFs in general? Or is it a limitation the browser sets? Anyone have any info on this or a workaround? The file size is < 100KB w/ about 5 frames, so I feel like its code related?

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Zach

Comment: maybe it would be quicker if you preloaded the image (make a quick google search "preload images javascript")

Comment: Open the gif directly, eg. www.yoursite.com/yourimage.gif, and compare load times. If it loads quicker directly then there might well be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: is the gif slow if you lose the javascript and just load it by itself?

Comment: @JCOC611 I posted the code, it actually does preload, so that's not the issue. I feel like it's a browser issue. I've tested on Safari and Firefox both are fairly low framerate for a 'No Delay' animation

Comment: @dstarh it's the same. Interesting. Maybe this is just a limitation of GIFs?

Comment: can you post the gif somewhere? my guess is it's the image and nothing to do with the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost impossible to control GIF framerates precisely as the playback varies depending on multitude of factors such as browser, connection, speed, computer speed etc. If you would like to control your animation precisely I recommend suing sprite strips and a library such as http://spritely.net/ for jQuery.

Comment: thanks! I think you're right it's acting differently on different browsers. I'll take a look at Spritely

Answer (score 0):

Make several copies of the .gif with different compression settings and swap them into the testing server.

This way you can observe the loading times for the same .gif with different file sizes and it might help you narrow down the issue.

We want to clarify whether it's the compression setting of the asset (file size) or the code that's loading the asset at run time.

If you confirm that it is the code, I would preload/cache the .gif.

Comment: @user: Actually the gif was preloaded - it has to do with playback speed. Although many applications (such as photoshop) allow you to control the frame-rate at which it plays back, when you upload to a server and run in a browser, the frame-rate does not run as fast as you'd like. I tested in several (Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome) and all seemed "capped". Just had to figure a way around that or use Flash (not an option for me).